# Generic REST API Golang

Tags: postgresql, rest, go

Searching SO for **Generic REST API Golang** gives 0 results. Searching Google gives 2 results. So this question is maybe not correctly formulated or it is impossible to achieve in Golang.

My goal is to avoid repeating similar code over and over again. So I am trying to make the code in Golang as generic as possible. Write once, use many.

This is my first attempt to create a generic REST API for select in Golang. The code below gives almost what I want:

But the result is presented in the Terminal. I have no idea how to redirect the result to the browser.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "time"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
   Connect()
   http.HandleFunc("/", Query)
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func Connect() {
   const (
   host = "127.0.0.1"
   port = 5432
   user = "test"
   password = "test"
   dbname  = "Test")

login := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require", host, port, user, password, dbname)
var err error
  db, err = sql.Open("postgres", login)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
err = db.Ping()
  if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

func Query(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

   var query string
   switch r.URL.String() {
   case "/getuser":
      query = "select * from getuser()"
   case "/getco":
      query = "select * from getco()"
   case "/etc"
      query = "select * from etc"
   default:
      query = ""
   }

  var err error
  var rows *sql.Rows

  rows, err = db.Query(query)
  if err != nil {
      http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
      return
   }
  defer rows.Close()

  cols, err := rows.Columns()
  vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
  for i := 0; i < len(cols); i++ {
      vals[i] = new(interface{})
      if i != 0 {
        fmt.Print("\t")
      }
      fmt.Print(cols[i])
   }
fmt.Println()

for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(vals...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(vals); i++ {
        if i != 0 {
            fmt.Print("\t")
        }
        printValue(vals[i].(*interface{}))
    }
    fmt.Println()
}


func printValue(pval *interface{}) {
    switch v := (*pval).(type) {
    case nil:
        fmt.Print("NULL")
    case bool:
        if v {
           fmt.Print("1")
        } else {
           fmt.Print("0")
        }
    case []byte:
        fmt.Print(string(v))
    case time.Time:
        fmt.Print(v.Format("2006-01-02"))
    default:
        fmt.Print(v)
    }
 }
```

Every attempt to write to the browser gives various type of errors:

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", vals...)
```

My questions are

1. How do I redirect the result to the browser?
2. Is there any better way to achieve this? (reuse generic code)

Comment: separate **DB Query** and **DB Connection** in separate functions.
while writing output to stdout using `fmt.Printf()` use `fmt.Fprintf(w, "pattern", vars)` this will write output to http response.

Comment: Yes, this redirect the "result" to the browser. But only garbage text like "pattern%!(EXTRA *interface {}=0xc4201aa2b0 etc". At the same time the result is still printed to the Terminal. Further clues?

Comment: You are using a type safe language to try and ignore type safety. Find a better hammer or generate the code.

Comment: @peter Can you elaborate this more? What is insecure and why?

Comment: I didn't say it is insecure. What I meant is that there's better options than using a statically typed language to then ignore the type system by putting interface{} everywhere. That's going to be messy. You might as well use a dynamically typed language like Ruby, Python, PHP.

Comment: @peter "rows.Columns()" is a dynamically (?) command from golang "database/sql". How can a standard command be messy? Forgive me, but I am a totally newbie on Golang and am only trying to understand.

Comment: The messy bit is how you have to deal with the actual rows, not the column names. It is much cleaner and simpler if you know what you're working with. And you haven't even written the code for inserts yet. Try it yourself. Write non-generic code for one of the endpoints and compare. You'll see that it is much shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to look at using existing packages like "mux" for calling REST APIs in browser. As a quick demo how you would do it as as follows:

your restapi.go cound have APIs as follows:

```
func SampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { //Assuming this is a POST request
    var example SomeSruct 
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&example) //Decode the POST body
    result := someLogicFunction(example) //call your generic function
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result) //encode the result to pass it back to browser
}
```

Now say you write a main.go and you are using mux package here is an example of how you would call this

main.go

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/testFunc",restapi.SampleAPI).Methods("POST") //This creates the route for your http request
    handler := cros.Default().Handler(router) //You will need this if you plan to deploy it in a server and call it externally for testing locally you don't need this
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)) //Port that the router is listening to
}
```

Now note that you will have to import the "github.com/gorilla/mux" and the "github.com/rs/cors" packages to use these but this way you can create REST APIs whic can be accessed by te browser. Similarly you could create a GET method and use parameters which you can grab in your function and perform any logical step.

If you build and install the above code you can POST to *localhost:8080/testFunc* over http using any web app and get results i your browser. If you had a GET request you could directly type the Url in the browser and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. write response with appropriahe HTTP hearers && status code

   ```
   import "net/http"

   func writeResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, contents []byte) {
       w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
       w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
       fmt.Fprintln(w, contents)
   }
   ```
2. sounds a little unclear, sorry

Comment: 1. So calling another function outside "func Query"?. How? 2. How to achieve generic REST API. I e write once use many times. Links, clues or whatever.